# Rails i18n : "fr" is not a valid locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I would like to translate my rails application in two languages, french and english but got some problem. I've got the following error:

```
"fr" is not a valid locale
```

In my config/application.rb:

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
I18n.config.available_locales = :fr
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

And in my controller, I receive the locale in parameters:

```
I18n.locale = export_params[:lang] || I18n.default_locale
```

I don't have any problem with the locale "en". My app is well translated but I've this error message when I use a different parameter than "en".

I use Rails 4.2.0

Comment: you need to provide configuration for `fr` in `config/locales/` as given for `en.yml`

Comment: I did that. I've had a config/locales/fr.yml with my translation but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, it works. I just need to restart the server.

Answer (score 3):

Check at your `application.rb` if `config.i18n.available_locales = :en` is set to your language and also check inside `config/locales` if you already heave your language.yml created there.

After all don't forget to reset your server

regards